# Is there any advantage of reencoding a 480p video as 1080p?

Tags: video, video-conversion, video-encoding

To be specific, I mean importing a 480p video into Movie Maker and exporting it as a 1080p MP4? Is there an advantage?

Comment: I would say it is a waste of disk space to increase what is going to be a  pixelated movie, but someone might know more than me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there's no advantage to this and you're just going to make the video file size larger for no reason at all. It's simply impossible to get a greater resolution than the source. Once you've captured a picture or video, the source size is forever your highest resolution. There are neat projects like [scale2x](http://www.scale2x.it/) that try to increase resolution and intelligently reconstruct the image to minimize pixelation, but it inevitably happens anyway.

Answer (score 3):

If you assume that the file will be viewed in a particular resolution -- for example, full HD is a reasonable assumption these days --, there may be an advantage to provide the video in the native resolution of the assumed player/viewer.

This will be the case if your converter's upscaling algorithm is better than that of the prospective player/viewer (and of course also if additional improvements are applied, like de-interlacing etc.).

This will depend on the software you use and on the assumed particular player(s), which become better and better because of faster hardware. Video hardware in particular is progressing fast, so the potential advantage of pre-upscaling is getting smaller.

I have no knowledge of the quality of Movie Maker's upscaling. Mulvya said in a comment that it performs a bicubic interpolation which doesn't seem too great. Quick googling sent me to [this site.](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/354538-Best-Upscale-Filters) Perhaps it's worth it to explore other programs.

Comment: True, but the question is specifically about Movie Maker, which probably does bicubic.

Comment: @Mulvya OK, I missed the Movie Maker reference (go figure -- I probably just read the title, cough). OK, quick googling shows that bicubic is not really great (sinc seems to be best)... my answer was simply motivated by experiencing non-HD material on early HD TVs which looked often terrible.